# bash: read string into array bash with spaces preserved

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, solaris

I have string "hi how are you"
I want to put this string into an array as shown below. But i want to preserve spaces. Any ideas on how to do that?

```
    a[0] a[1] a[2]    3   4 5   6     .... should have
     h    i   <space> h   o w <space> .... and so on.
```

Comment: probably not a duplicate, most answers cannot handle spaces...

Comment: exactly. I tried to search as much as i could but couldnt find how to handle spaces.;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval a=( $(echo "hi how are you" | sed "s/\(.\)/'\1' /g") )
```

It's really ugly, maybe somebody can come up with something without `eval`...

Comment: do you mind explaining the sed part?

Comment: run that part alone: `echo "hi how are you" | sed "s/\(.\)/'\1' /g"`. Replaces every character with a quoted one

Comment: silly question! should have done that! Thank you Karoly! That works! cheers!

Answer (score 3):

One way, sure there will be better solutions but this seems to work for me:

```
unset arr; IFS=; for c in $(sed 's/./&\n/g' <<<"hi how are you"); do arr+=("$c"); done; echo "${arr[@]}"
```

It yields:

```
h
i

h
o
w

a
r
e

y
o
u
```

Comment: thank you Birei! I guess i am spoilt for choice ! I appreciate your response sir!

Comment: Thank you, your `IFS=''` trick helped me in my own problem (preserving spaces in an array of filenames)!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not fast, but avoids the need for `sed`:

```
z=()
while read -n 1 x; do
    z+=( "$x" )
done <<<"hi how are you"
```